unzip several files from one archive to specific output folder with R and command line
I have a password protected zip archive containing several files. I want to unzip this archive and put the unzipped files into one specific folder.
I was able to unzip the archive, however the files in the zip archive were put into my working directory.
I know I could now move the files from there to my dedicated folder or even change the working directory to my desired output folder before unzipping, but I was wondering if and how I can specify an output folder/path/directory directrly in the command line command. I tried to simply add an output path to the command, which didn't work.
Any ideas?
Here's my code for extracting the files to my working directory.
password <- "abc"

system(command = paste0("unzip -o -P ",
                        password,
                        " ",
                        shQuote("C:/Users/User/testfile.zip")),
       wait = TRUE)

(Let's assume I would want to put the files into  "D:/test/")

Try unzip --help .  My unzip command supports a -d flag after which the output directory path is specified.

Instead of shQuote("C:/Users/User/testfile.zip") try "'C:/Users/User/testfile.zip'".

@G.Grothendieck: that worked perfectly fine. Happy to accept it as an answer...

@RuiBarradas: out of curiosity, What's the difference or advantage of the single quotes?

@deschen I had problems with Windows in the past, it only accepted double quotes around the command, the outermost quotes had to be double.
